# Check for NaN or Inf in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

How to check if a real variable in SystemVerilog is at 'Not a Number' (NaN) or infinite (Inf)? Do system tasks exist for this purpose like isnan() or isinf() in C99?

Comment: `if($realtobits(realvariable)==64'b1111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)` works for me. But it is awkward.

Answer (score 1):

I now use

```
function real_is_number; 
  input real in;
  reg [63:0] in_bits;
  begin
    in_bits=$realtobits(in);
    real_is_number = ~&in_bits[62:52];
  end
endfunction
```

to detect any real value which is not an ordinary number.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
let isnan(r) = {$realtobits(r)}[62:52] == '1 && {$realtobits(r)}[51:0] != '0;
```

Although the SystemVerilog LRM references IEEE 754 for representing floating point numbers, it does not define the results of real operations that could produce *NaN* or *Inf*. So use with caution.

Comment: This may work. Unfortunately slices of concatenations are not supported by my simulator (Synopsys/vcs).